# server side pagination with angular and Php

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5, pagination

I am having some problem with angularJs , while trying to do server side pagination.
Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="body-container detail-box">
    <div class="table">
        <div ui-grid="gridOptions"  ui-grid-pagination class=""></div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

JS File:

```
     module.exports = managerShowEditController;
},{}],12:[function(require,module,exports){
var managerIndexController = function($scope, $http, $resource, $stateParams, uiGridConstants, gridPaginSorting, config) {
             // some code
    }
```

The error is :
[image]

I am unable to use 'uiGridConstants, gridPaginSorting and config'
any idea whats going wrong ?

Comment: How are you injecting this dependency?

Comment: I am new to angularJs , do we need to include a separate file for 'uiGridConstants, gridPaginSorting and config' or will it be derived from angularjs file ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to include it in your main index.html
You'll need to include it there though I suggest you use a task automation runner like Grunt or Gulp which will handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the package name to your app.js file. For Example : `'ui.grid'`